# Is there a character to depict a large number?

Tags: notation

Does a symbol exist to depict an arbitrarily large, finite number?

Comment: Of course, $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "arbitrarily large" here, but I like to use $N$ for large integers.

Comment: What about $\Huge N$?

Comment: $\varepsilon$. $ $

Comment: You mean $1/\varepsilon$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common in number theory to write $c \gg 1$ to mean that $c$ is a sufficiently large (but finite) constant.  The $\gg$ notation is [Vinogradov's Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_.28Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau.2C_Hardy.2C_and_Vinogradov_notations.29).

Answer (score 5):

Symbols (like $\pi$) are used to denote fixed values, while "arbitrarily large" by its very nature is not fixed.  It might, for example appear in an existential quantifier as in $\exists N > n \dots$ (read, "there exists a number $N$ greater than $n$ such that $\dots$").